# React - problems with checkbox

Tags: reactjs, function, checkbox

I am trying to create a component with four options. The user is supposed to choose only one option. So if the user chooses another option, the previosluy selected ones should change to false. This is my code:

```
const riddles_ = [{
    id:2,
    options: ['A grandson','A daughter','A father','A nephew'],
    state_: [false,false,false,false]
    }]

function toggleToDo(o){ 
        riddles_.state_ = [false,false,false,false]
        riddles_.state_[o] = true
        console.log(riddles_.state_)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check1" checked={riddles_.state_[0]} onClick={(o)=>toggleToDo(0)}/>
            {riddles_.options[0]}
            <div className='space'></div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check2" checked={riddles_.state_[1]} onClick={(o)=>toggleToDo(1)}/>
            {riddles_.options[1]}
            <div className='space'></div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check3" checked={riddles_.state_[2]} onClick={(o)=>toggleToDo(2)}/>
            {riddles_.options[2]}
            <div className='space'></div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check4" checked={riddles_.state_[3]} onClick={(o)=>toggleToDo(3)}/>
            {riddles_.options[3]}
        </div>
    )
}
```

When the user clicks on a checkbox, it just turns true or false, and generates no change in the others. I know the riddles_.state_ array is changing but the checkbox don´t seem to be able to take its value.

Comment: Your not re rendering the component. You need to use the `useState()` hook.

Comment: By the way, a better practice is to use radio button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a best practice to use set method frome useState hooks when u work with state, using react functional components.

Example :

```
const init_state = [false,false,false,false]
const [checked_state, setCheckedState] = useState(init_state);

function toggleToDo(o){ 
        const current_state = [false,false,false,false]
        current_state[o] = true;
        setCheckedState(current_state);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" checked={checked_state[0]} onClick={(o)=>toggleToDo(0)}/>
            option1
            <div className='space'></div>
            <input type="checkbox" checked={checked_state[1]} onClick={(o)=>toggleToDo(1)}/>
            option2
            <div className='space'></div>
            <input type="checkbox" checked={checked_state[2]} onClick={(o)=>toggleToDo(2)}/>
            option3
            <div className='space'></div>
            <input type="checkbox" checked={checked_state[3]} onClick={(o)=>toggleToDo(3)}/>
            option4
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I'm adding a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-mcclintock-pxype) with a working demo. It's doing the same thing as in Bona's answer.